# Java Generics with Composite Key and Wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have a pair interface e.g.

```
public interface CompositeKeyType<K1, K2> {
    public K1 getKey1();
    public K2 getKey2();
}
```

And an implementation:

```
package com.bcsg.creditcardrecords;

public class CompositeKeyImplementer<K1, K2> implements
    CompositeKeyType<K1, K2> {

    private K1 key1;
    private K2 key2;

    public CompositeKeyImplementer() {
        this.key1 = null;
        this.key2 = null;
    }

    public CompositeKeyImplementer(K1 key1, K2 key2) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (key1.equals(key2)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("both keys cannot be equal");
        }
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
    }

     @Override
     public K1 getKey1() {
        return this.key1;
    }

    @Override
    public K2 getKey2() {
        return this.key2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof CompositeKeyImplementer<?, ?>)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!(((CompositeKeyImplementer<?, ?>)     obj).getKey1().equals(this.key1))
            || !(((CompositeKeyImplementer<?, ?>) obj).getKey2()
                    .equals(this.key2))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now....I also have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractBankCardDetailsHolder<K, V> {

    private NavigableMap<K, V> cardData;

    public AbstractBankCardDetailsHolder() {
        cardData = new TreeMap<K, V>();
    }

    public AbstractBankCardDetailsHolder(K key, V value){
        cardData.put(key, value);
    }

    public NavigableMap<K, V> getCardData(){
        return this.cardData;
    }

    public void setCardData(NavigableMap<K,V> cadData){
        this.cardData.clear();
        this.cardData.putAll(cardData);
    }              
}
```

Which I am generalising here (it is coming up with errors):

```
public class CompositeKeyBasedCreditCardDetailsHolder<? extends K, ? extends V> extends
                AbstractBankCardDetailsHolder<? extends K, ? extends V> {

            private CompositeKeyImplementer<? extends K, ? extends K> numberProviderPair;

            // ....... TBC

}
```

I was under the impression that ? wildcard means ?TypeUnknown? and it will resolve the types @Runtime. However, I notices whilsts writing this questiont that my `CompositeKeyImplementer.java` class has got wildcards in the `equals` method too. Is this something that I won't be able to achieve because JVM cannot resolve the different wildcard arrangements such as this one during runtime?

Comment: You have now edited this question twice, each edit fundamentally changes the question - first you changed the `CompositeKeyImplementor` definition 25 minutes after asking the question, and then changed your `numberProviderPair` field to a completely different type and field name nearly an hour later. Please **treat this question as a question at a point in time, accept an answer which helps you, and then ask a new question as your understanding of the problem changes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can work out from your sample code:

1) Your `CompositeKeyImplementer` needs to be generic. It implements a generic interface, and you later refer to it as a generic type.

```
public class CompositeKeyImplementer<K1, K2> implements CompositeKeyType<K, V> {
  ...
```

2) You want to have a `CompositeKeyImplementor<K1, K2>` with any type arguments that are subtypes of `K` as a field in your `CompositeKeyBasedCreditCardDetailsHolder` class.

Therefore you use the wildcards *on invocation* of that `CompositeKeyImplementor` as *type arguments*. You don't use them as *type parameters* in the generic type declaration for `CompositeKeyBasedCreditCardDetailsHolder`

```
public class CompositeKeyBasedCreditCardDetailsHolder<K, V> extends
AbstractBankCardDetailsHolder<K, V> {

    private CompositeKeyImplementer<? extends K, ? extends K> numberProviderPair;

    // ....... TBC

}
```

With this you are saying:

1. I am declaring a generic `CompositeKeyBasedCreditCardDetailsHolder` with type parameters `K, V`.
2. That type has a field called `numberProviderPair`
3. Which itself is a generic type `CompositeKeyImplementer<K1, K2>`
4. and in fact which itself can be *any* `CompositeKeyImplementer<K1, K2>` where the type parameters `K1, K2` are a subtype (inclusive) of `K`
5. i.e. they are upper bounded by the type parameter `K` defined by `CompositeKeyBasedCreditCardDetailsHolder`

Note that the type arguments for `K1, K2` are not restricted to the same type. For example: this is possible:

```
// note the arguments for K1, K2. Both extend Number
CompositeKeyImplementer<Integer, Double> cki = 
    new CompositeKeyImplementer<Integer, Double>();
// note the argument for K is Number
CompositeKeyBasedCreditCardDetailsHolder<Number, String> cdh = 
    new CompositeKeyBasedCreditCardDetailsHolder<Number, String>(cki);
```

I recommend (re-)reading [the java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) on wildcards, and possibly also [Angelika Langer on wildcard type arguments](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#Topic2) as they have a lot of information on what wildcards are used for and how.